git commit not working github (GIT: Failed to execute git )
I tried it in CMD/Gitbash/Vscode/Rubymine
In vs code I get:

IN ALL TERMINAL'S I GET:

THIS IS THE GitLog ()even though I try to create the file manually  it doesn't work any way:
10:27:56.174: [app-front] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- .husky/pre-commit
10:27:56.239: [app-front] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit -F C:\Users\admmd\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt --
10:28:09.247: [app-front] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false add --ignore-errors -A -f -- .husky/pre-commit
10:28:09.288: [app-front] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false commit -F C:\Users\admmd\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-.txt --

git bash (I tried re installing):
Error: Could not fork child process: Resource temporarily unavailable (-1).

DLL rebasing may be required; see 'rebaseall / rebase --help'.


I think you need to initialize a Git repo for your project. For that enter git init in the source folder of your expected Git repo.

nope bro I have been working with git normally for this project and suddenly it doesn't work, I did try git init doesn't work

Do not post pictures of text.

But you haven't fixed it.

@matt done, I only left the first pics, I found the solution, but I will keep that in mind and I think that's why someone down voted

what I found was:

Windows Security
Click App & browser control
Scroll down and click Exploit protection settings
Find the Force randomization for images section and select Off by default
Reboot



How certain are you that steps 1-4 are relevant? Did you try rebooting on its own, without changing any security settings?

I didn't downvote, but disabling an important security feature sounds inadvisable. Here's the Git for Windows issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1412. There's also a script attached that only disables ASLR for the Git binaries (if I understand correctly).

@mercator thank you, not sure but by default for windows it isn't activated
